# Get information from checkbox for creating groups

Tags: html, mysql, angularjs, web, angularjs-scope

I must create a web app with angularjs.

I must create a web app where I have the possibility to create groups of athlete. I must store them in localstorage. The elements of the athletes which I must store are the id. How can I do this?
Someone can help me?

I have this code in controller:

```
$scope.selection=[];
            // toggle selection for a given employee by name
            $scope.toggleSelection = function toggleSelection(id_athlete) {
                var idx = $scope.selection.indexOf(id_athlete);
                // is currently selected
                if (idx > -1) {
                    $scope.selection.splice(idx, 1);
                }
                // is newly selected
                 else {
                    $scope.selection.push(id_athlete);
                 }


                window.localStorage['$scope.selection'] = JSON.stringify($scope.selection);
                $scope.selection = JSON.parse(window.localStorage['$scope.selection'] || '{}');
```

the problem of this part is that in this way I don't see the id but I only see the name but it's not important.

The html code is :

```
<input ng-hide="see" id="group.name" type="checkbox" ng-checked="selection.indexOf(group.id) >" ng-click="toggleSelection(group.id)" />
<!-- -->
<button ng-hide="see" ng-click="save(group.id)" >Salva</button>
```

Ok now how can I create the group?
Please help me

Comment: I hardly understand the question. Where do you want to create a the group object and depending on which information? Where doesn the `group.name` and `group.id` come from? And why do you map `group.id` to `id_athlete`. And what do you mean by **"I must only see the name and the name is not important"** ? Very confusing.

Comment: Ok... the sentence is not correct, you delete must. And I must create a web app where I have the possibility to create groups of athlete. I must store them in localstorage. The elements of the athletes which I must store are the id. Where can I do this? @Michael

Comment: You need to create a form where you can enter the **group.name** the **group.id** should be assigend by the DB. Or do you want to save everything in the `localStore`? Then you create the group and assign the athletes.

Comment: I've a DB with the athletes. The groups of athlete must be stored in localstore. Can I enter the group name and the group id after I choose the athletes to add to the group? or is it more difficult?

Comment: Sure you can do that in one step. You just have to design your GUI and form that way.

Comment: Ok I done but I can to store only one group, not more. But now I try to do the next pass. I store the group in localstore, now how can I switch in other page how can I see the list of my group? Thanks @Michael

Comment: Probably a local DB (also available in HTML5) would fit better. If you wanna stick with **localStore** you have to include the group structure in your string as well and save it with the group id. `window.localStorage[group.id] = JSON.stringify({groupName: group.id, athletes: $scope.selection});`